# libx264 codec not enabled in ffmpeg ubuntu 18.04

Tags: docker, ffmpeg, ubuntu-18.04, codec, libx264

I have some weird codec installation issues with the following docker image.

```
ARG PYTORCH="1.8.0"
ARG CUDA="11.1"
ARG CUDNN="8"
FROM pytorch/pytorch:${PYTORCH}-cuda${CUDA}-cudnn${CUDNN}-devel

ENV TORCH_CUDA_ARCH_LIST="6.0 6.1 7.0 8.0+PTX"
ENV TORCH_NVCC_FLAGS="-Xfatbin -compress-all"
ENV CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="$(dirname $(which conda))/../"

# https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/issues/1632
RUN apt-key del 7fa2af80
RUN apt-key adv --fetch-keys https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64/3bf863cc.pub
RUN apt-key adv --fetch-keys https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        git nano ninja-build p7zip-full imagemagick wget unzip \
        libglib2.0-0 libsm6 libxrender-dev libxext6 libturbojpeg \
        libxrender1 libfontconfig1 freeglut3-dev llvm-6.0-tools curl \
        amqp-tools ffmpeg libx264-dev \
    && apt --fix-broken install \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    # for visualizing
    && wget https://github.com/mmatl/travis_debs/raw/master/xenial/mesa_18.3.3-0.deb \
    && dpkg -i ./mesa_18.3.3-0.deb || true \
    && apt install -f \
    && git clone https://github.com/mmatl/pyopengl.git \
    && pip install ./pyopengl
```

First of all, libx264 is supposed to be installed by a simple `apt-get install ffmpeg` in ubuntu 18.04.5. Indeed I see that it is being installed in the installation instructions but for some reason, it's not enabled. This is confirmed when running `ffmpeg -codecs | grep 264`, which doesn't show `libx264` (only h264, libopenh264 are there).

In addition, I also compiled [from source](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu), explicitly enabling libx264 during installation. It didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I also had `ffmpeg` installed with `conda`. So:

`conda remove --force ffmpeg -y`

`apt-get update && apt-get install -y ffmpeg`

Comment: Thanks! `conda remove --force ffmpeg` worked for me. Otherwise, conda kept trying to "upgrade" pytorch to the condaforge version whenever I removed `ffmpeg`.

Comment: you are a savior thanks a ton